# Athena: Custom Apache log format regex issue

Tags: amazon-athena

I have a custom format apache access log with lines like:

```
Jan  1 23:59:59 ip-172-70-12-5 172.70.1.146 - - [01/Jan/2018:23:59:59 +0000] "GET /someurl HTTP/1.1" 200 22854 "somdomain.com" "5a4acbvv7f7d222" "-" "" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10" 486029 "180.80.80.62"
```

In Athena, I have a table set up to process this using a regex, here is the table DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_access_log`(
  `remoteaddr` string COMMENT '', 
  `remotelogname` string COMMENT '', 
  `user` string COMMENT '', 
  `day` string COMMENT '', 
  `month` string COMMENT '', 
  `year` string COMMENT '', 
  `request` string COMMENT '', 
  `status` string COMMENT '', 
  `bytes_string` string COMMENT '', 
  `tenant` string COMMENT '', 
  `xrequestid` string COMMENT '', 
  `userid` string COMMENT '', 
  `referrer` string COMMENT '', 
  `browser` string COMMENT '', 
  `requesttime` string COMMENT '', 
  `originatorip` string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([0-9]*)\\/([a-zA-Z]*)\\/([0-9]*):[\\w:]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4}\\] \\\"(.+?)\\\" (\\S+) (\\S+) \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\" \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\" \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\" \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\" \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\" (\\S+) \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"$') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mybucket/access-logs'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1526982859')
```

The problem is a preview on this table comes back with every column showing an empty value.

I have tested the regex via an online Java tester and the expression correctly returns all 16 elements as expected.

If I run SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_access_log then as expected I get the number of rows I am expecting, so it seems it was possible to load the files in my S3 bucket. This leads me to think this is a regex issue.

Any ideas what is wrong with the regex?